# How to sync git branch from master without overwriting branch updates?

Tags: git

I'm trying to solve a Git repository problem that I'm sure is commonplace but I don't have enough experience using Git to solve it and I just don't think I'm phrasing it properly so I'm not finding the answer.

I have a private repository that only I commit to. Several months ago, I created a branch from master and worked on a lot of changes. For various reasons, those changes have sat there unmerged until now, but at this point the master branch has been updated many times.

I know that I can run something like `git diff --name-status master` in the branch to tell me what files differ between them and what kind of update it is, but is there a way to safely update the branch with the master but only for the files that were not modified in the branch, so that I don't clobber any of my branch updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is (almost) always additive in its operations. If you run the command `git merge master` you will merge all of the updates in the master branch into your branch as a new merge commit. Git tracks individual lines of code - so you may get some merge conflicts where someone else touched the same lines of code.

If you ever want to go back to your current branch, just go back to your last commit- just before you merged master in.